# log4j: logging works when package inside app, but not when package contributed by a JAR

Tags: java, log4j

This isn't just a rehash of how to do package-specific logging. I think I've got that nailed. It's about logging not being done when the package is moved out to a JAR shared with others.

Originally, I wrote some special logging into my web application which worked, putting special statements into a file separate from *catalina.out*. Later, it seemed useful to share this facility with other, cooperating web applications, so we moved the package, consisting of one interface and one class, to a utilities JAR. While the information-gathering continued successfully, the output to the "special" log file, separate from *catalina.out*, ceased.

When I relocate a copy of the package back into my application, the logging begins working again as originally designed.

The package name remains the same no matter whether it's physically part of my application code or linked in from a consumed library JAR.

I'm struggling to understand a class linked from a JAR is seemingly excluded from the logging scheme while it works flawlessly when simply part of the application code.

Thank you for taking the time to look at this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's *log4j.properties*:

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 1) Standard Tomcat log (tomcat): /var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out
# 2) Splunkable output log (splunkable): /var/log/tomcat6/myapp.log.
# 3) Console used when debugging myapp from Eclipse.
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE,tomcat,console

# Rolling-file appender for Tomcat -----------------------------------------------------------
log4j.appender.tomcat.Threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.tomcat=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.tomcat.DatePattern='.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.tomcat.File=${catalina.home}/logs/catalina.out
log4j.appender.tomcat.file.MaxFileSize=500Mb
log4j.appender.tomcat.file.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.tomcat.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.tomcat.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Splunkable log -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
log4j.appender.splunkable.Threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.splunkable=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.splunkable.File=${catalina.home}/logs/myapp.log
log4j.appender.splunkable.MaxFileSize=1Gb
log4j.appender.splunkable.MaxBackupIndex=7
log4j.appender.splunkable.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.splunkable.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}: %m%n

# Set the additivity flag to false to avoid propagating the rather verbose splunkable
# output to the normal Tomcat and console logs. Is this mere superstition?
  log4j.category.com.acme.web.myapp.logging=TRACE,splunkable
log4j.additivity.com.acme.web.myapp.logging=false

# This logs output to the Eclipse console when running in that mode --------------------------
log4j.appender.console.Threshold=TRACE
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.SimpleLayout
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Is all logging disappearing, or just logging for specific classes?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Oh, yeah, the "normal" logging that goes to the console and to catalina.out is intact and as I want it. It's the "splunkable" logging that's not making it into myapp.log unless the interface and class in the package com.acme.web.myapp.logging is inside the project (rather than contributed by utils.jar).

Comment: Are you sure that the correct `log4j.properties` is getting loaded? When you change how you're packaging things up, a different version (older, included in some other jar, etc.) may be running instead.

Comment: There is but one, single copy of log4j.properties. It lives in the application and there is none in the library (I just re-checked that). And, it's the one I posted above. There are no other attempts at configuring logging, even using Java code. We rely solely on the contents of the posted file.

Comment: You've confirmed that the class you moved into the jar is actually getting loaded and executed?

Comment: Yes. And, this is the crux of the question. The only way I'm able to get anything in myapp.log is to locate the package in myapp's code rather than via including the JAR it normally resides inside.

Comment: There's a possibility of an execution-order problem here, if the client class is getting loaded (and initializing a static `Logger`) before log4j is fully up. I'm afraid I'm out of ideas (I switched to slf4j long ago), but this really sounds like a `ClassLoader` getting confused (and I know that, for example, years' worth of production versions of Jetty didn't handle jar resource searching correctly).

Comment: I'll concentrate my efforts following that idea. I really appreciate your comments and help. Sorry not to be offering an answer to subsequent readers of this thread. If I stumble upon anything, I'll make an addendum to my posted question or answer it.